# Ripple effect goes out of view's parent area in API21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-drawable, ripple

I have a code for setting a ripple effect as the background of a custom frameLayot.

```
 ViewCompat.setBackground(myFrameLayout, getDiscRipple(getContext()));
```

and

```
  private Drawable getDiscRipple(Context context) {
    int myRippleResourceId =
        getThemeResourceId(
            context, android.R.attr.actionBarItemBackground, /*defValue=*/ 0);
    Drawable myRipple = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, myRippleResourceId);
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
      ((RippleDrawable) myRipple).setRadius(RippleDrawable.RADIUS_AUTO);
    }
    return myRipple;
  }
```

When I run it with API-21, I see the round ripple extends bigger than the view's parent area.

It's not like "Borderless" ripple effect, but clips.

How can I set the ripple to extend at most to the view's parent area?

I have tried:

```
  android:clipChildren="true"
  android:clipToPadding="true"
```

without much success.

see:

[image]